# Get full size and resized images in the same loop in media.phtml

Tags: product, image, media, rwd

I'm working with the new Magento default responsive theme (RWD).

On product view page I need to get the url of full size dimensions images.

In catalog/product/view/media.phtml I find

```
<?php
        $i=0;
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
            $_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                              ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())
                              ->keepFrame(false)
                              ->constrainOnly(true)
                              ->resize(1200);
    ?>
        <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
             class="gallery-image"
             src="<?php echo $_imageUrl; ?>"
             data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $_imageUrl; ?>" />
    <?php
        $i++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
```

As I said, I need to add one data attribute of  tag with the url of full size image so I try this way

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image):
        $_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                          ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())
                          ->keepFrame(false)
                          ->constrainOnly(true)
                          ->resize(1200);

        $_imageUrl_full = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                          ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile());

?>
    <img id="image-<?php echo $i; ?>"
         class="gallery-image"
         src="<?php echo $_imageUrl; ?>"
         data-zoom-image="<?php echo  $_imageUrl; ?>"
         data-zoom-image-full="<?php echo  $_imageUrl_full; ?> />
<?php
    $i++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

...but I get the same image url (the full size one) for both "data-zoom-image" and "data-zoom-image-full".

I also try to clone the $_image object but no result.

Any advice?

P.S. I saw the question [Issue with getting product image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/issue-with-getting-product-image) but I'm looping through media gallery images and not between products. My objective is to get different sized images and not different product images. And Last, as I said, I try to clone the $_image with no luck.

Comment: I don't see in your post where you are using `clone`...?

Comment: The "clone way" is not in the code: i write that "I also try to clone the $_image object but no result."

Comment: Then your problem is the same as the other post. The issue is the reference and the helper instance, regardless of multiple products or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get full image try below code

```
    $_imageUrl_full=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config') 
->getMediaUrl($_image->getFile());
```

`$_imageUrl` is right for  small image

Comment: It works. Has it some issue with image caching or not?

Comment: Yes, you cannot create a product more than one  cache image in Same page,

Comment: @gattieri: Please verify the answer if it completes the requirement